# Selecting elements by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have following table

```
   <table class="testing">        
                        <tbody>                
           <tr class="formm">
                         <td>
                         <td><input type="text" value="334.00" id="inS" name="s1003"                 class="testing"></td>
                    </tr>
           <tr class="formm">
                         <td>
                         <td><input type="text" value="324.00" id="inS" name="s1004"  
                         class="testing"></td>   
                    </tr>
          <tr class="formm">
                         <td>
                         <td><input type="text" value="324.00" id="inS" name="s1005"                 class="testing"></td>       
                    </tr>

     </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to read value of each row so I can apply some formatting and than update it using jquery.

```
  $('.testing tr.formm').each(function () {
            var num = $(this).find('input[name=s1003]').val();
            alert(num);
            $(this).find('#inS').val(process(num));
       });
```

When I run the above code I keep getting alert for num as undefined. How can I fix this error.
Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: There must be something that you're not showing us here as the above code works fine. See this working example... jsfiddle.net/QLeY9

Comment: Thanks. In my code when i changed the class name it started to work. Have no idea why.